# Print matching regex group in grep

Tags: regex, unix

I have this text `https://bitbucket.com/user/repo.git` and I want to print `repo`, the content between `/` and `.git`, without including delimiters. I have this:

```
echo https://bitbucket.com/user/repo.git | grep -E -o '\/(.*?)\.git'
```

But it prints `/repo.git`. How can I print just `repo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[^/]+(?=\.git$)` pattern with `-P` option:

```
echo https://bitbucket.com/user/repo.git | grep -P -o '[^/]+(?=\.git$)'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/7F4eVz)

The `[^/]+(?=\.git$)` pattern matches 1+ chars other than `/` that are followed with `.git` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to do that

```
echo https://bitbucket.com/user/repo.git | sed -e 's/^.\*\\/\\(.\*\\).git$/\1/g'
```